# Value of Base tag appended to URL after component load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is using Angular 4.  In my layout I have a base tag that looks like this:

```
<base href="/src/">
```

I am setting everything up and I just added Angular Routing.  Now right after my base component loads my URL is appended with 'src'.

Here is my routes file:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './Components/Home/home.component';

export const AppRouting: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

I did not see this prior to adding the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this. For reference, my app folder is under a src directory, not in the root of my project.  Here is what I did.

Change the base tag to:

```
<base href="/">
```

Update my main.js call from:

```
<script>
    System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

to:

```
<script>
    System.import('src/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Then in my systemjs.config.js I had to change these lines:

```
map: {
    //app is within the app folder
    'app': 'app',
```

to:

```
map: {
    //app is within the app folder
    'app': 'src/app',
```

and I also had to change:

```
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
},
```

to:

```
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'src/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
},
```

Comment: Joe - are your (at)angular calls working correctly?  I made the changes you mentioned (I am trying to implement angular in an MVC app) and am getting errors with the (at)angular references saying "Can't find module '(at)angular/core'

Comment: NM - it must have been something else, this worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key purpose of the base tag *is* for routing. This is from the docs:

> Most routing applications should add a  element to the
>   index.html as the first child in the  tag to tell the router how
>   to compose navigation URLs.
>
> If the app folder is the application root, as it is for the sample
>   application, set the href value exactly as shown here.

https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href

At development time, it is most often set to "/" so the routes will run from root. At deployment, you change it to the folder on the server containing your application.

Comment: see my answer for more details on what I actually had to do to make that work.  It is not as simple as just changing the href to "/".  You pointed me in the right direction, but this answer is incomplete